# Implementing python regex lookbehind to parse sentence with variable characteristics

Tags: python, regex

Say I'm trying to parse out whether a sentence contains the term blue or green fries.  There can be any number of spaces or terms at the beginning, end, and middle of the sentence between the relevant terms (blue|green) and "fries."  I also want to negate the term "no."  However, when I try the regex below, it matches the sentence even though I'm attempting a negative look-behind.

```
re.search(r'(?<!no).*(?:blue|green).*fries', 'there is no apparent green big fries with soda.')
```

What am I not understanding about negative look-behinds, and how I can modify the regex to do want I want it to?

**Example valid match:**

```
'blue fries'

'I really like green, yellow, banana fries that are big'
```

**Example invalid match:**

```
'there is no apparent green big fries with soda.'

'no blue fries'

'no green fries with burgers.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `(?<!no).*` asserts that from the current position, there is not `no` directly to the left and will then match the whole line.

That assertion will be true directly at the first position, and will match the whole line.

Then it will match either blue or green and fries, not taking *no* into account any more.

---

You could assert that *no* is not present in the line by changing `(?<!no)` into `^(?!.*\bno\b)`.

The word boundaries `\b` are used to prevent the words being part of a larger word.

```
^(?!.*\bno\b).*\b(?:blue|green)\b.*\bfries\b.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\bno\b)` Assert that *no* is not present
- `.*\b(?:blue|green)\b` Match either blue or green
- `.*\bfries\b.*` Match fries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rz27R4/1)

Comment: The necessity of the anchor is difficult for me.  If I use the above regex without the ^ anchor on 'there is no apparent green big fries with soda.', it does match 'o apparent green big fries with soda.'

Comment: @Razorocean If you don't use the anchor, the negative lookahead `(?!.*\bno\b)` will keep on checking until the assertion is true. It becomes true when there is no occurrence of `no` at the right, will be at the position after the `n` in `there is n` From there on it will try to match the rest of the pattern, which it can, and the result will be `o apparent green big fries with soda.` But if you use the assertion right after the `^`, the rule is that from the current position (which is at the start of the start) there can not be `no` at the right. If there is, the assertion fails and no match.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex in `python`:

```sh
^(?!.*\bno\b)(?=.*\b(?:blue|green)\b).*\bfries\b.*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ad9gTL/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*\bno\b)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match when we have `no` anywhere
- `(?=.*\b(?:blue|green)\b)`: Positive lookahead to assert that line has word `blue` or `green`
- `.*\bfries\b.*`: Match a line that has word `fries` anywhere